# Generate different js bundles for each component using @angular/elements

Tags: angular, angular7, web-component, custom-element, angular-elements

I have a huge Angular application where a couple of components are exported as `@angular/elements`.

These components (although they still use shared services and components) are used in a different section of the website which is not part of the Single Page Application, but it is a stand-alone page delivered by the server.

The exported *angular elements*  work fine in the new page, but I don't consider acceptable load the whole SPA bundle (which si 5MB+) just to render two components. How can I generate a different javascript file for each angular elements?

I'd like to render my components like this:

```
<my-first-component />
<script src="./my-first-component.js"></script>

<my-second-component>
<script src="./my-second-component.js"></script>
```

But if the page generates a single bundle, the components (or, better, the custom elements) won't be independent by each other! And it's obvious that, in this context, **concatanation doesn't work**.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you found something? I needed as well, so I found this: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-compile-your-angular-components-library-into-web-components-47ff0ac73bd7

Comment: @Pnct the closest thing that I found was [this seed](https://github.com/flash-me/angular-micro-frontends)

Comment: I'm not much up-to-date, but I suppose that Angular has incredibly increased support to microfrontends, so this shouldn't be an issue nowadays